# ggplot and maps: problem with filtering country names

Tags: ggplot2, maps, r-sf

I try to create a map of the Middle East and North Africa region including country names. The map is defined by latitude and longitude coordinates. Several non-MENA countries are included in the resulting map, and I want to label with country names only the countries belonging to the region by defining them using the 'filter' function with a vector of country names. After having inserted the filter function, I get the error message: "Error in data.matrix(data) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'".
The map writes out fine when I don't include the filter with the vector of country names.

The following code runs fine:

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill= "antiquewhite") +
  geom_text(data = world_points , aes(x=X, y=Y, label=name),
            color = "darkblue", fontface = "bold", check_overlap = TRUE) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 20, y = 35, label = "MØNA", 
           fontface = "italic", color = "grey22", size = 6) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-18.0, 72.0), ylim = c(11.5, 45.0), expand = FALSE) +
  xlab("lengdegrader") + ylab("breddegrader") +
  ggtitle("Midtøsten og Nord-Afrika") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "aliceblue"))
```

But this produces the error. Something must be wrong in the geom_text function, but I cannot figure out what:

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill = "antiquewhite") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-18.0, 72.0), ylim = c(11.5, 45.0), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = world_points %>% 
              filter(name %in% c('Egypt', 'Tunisia', 'Algeria', 'Libya', 
                                 'Morocco', 'Sudan', 'Jordan', 'Israel', 
                                 'Palestine', 'Syria', 'Iraq', 'Turkey',
                                 'Iran', 'Afghanistan', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Kuwait', 
                                 'United Arab Emirates', 'Qatar', 'Oman', 'Yemen', 'Bahrain',
                                  'Lebanon')), aes(x=X, y=Y, label=name),
              color = "darkblue", size = 3, check_overlap = FALSE) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 20, y = 35, label = "MØNA", 
           fontface = "italic", color = "grey22", size = 6) +
  
  xlab("lengdegrader") + ylab("breddegrader") +
  ggtitle("Midtøsten og Nord-Afrika") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "aliceblue"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When putting text on maps plotted using `ggplot2::geom_sf()` you will be better served by `ggplot2::geom_sf_text()` (the sf part is important!) than plain `ggplot2::geom_text()`.

This function will take the text position from the  `{sf}` object that serves as `data` - thus removing the need to specify the x and y coordinates (the information is present in `data` already). Label argument works as expected

To sum it up:

- change `geom_text` call to `geom_sf_text`
- remove x and y coordinates from your `aes()` call

You will want to tune the label placement and what not, but it is a start...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

world <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries() %>% 
  mutate(name = NAME_ENGL)
world_points <- st_centroid(world)


ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill = "antiquewhite") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-18.0, 72.0), ylim = c(11.5, 45.0), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_sf_text(data = world_points %>% 
              filter(name %in% c('Egypt', 'Tunisia', 'Algeria', 'Libya', 
                                 'Morocco', 'Sudan', 'Jordan', 'Israel', 
                                 'Palestine', 'Syria', 'Iraq', 'Turkey',
                                 'Iran', 'Afghanistan', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Kuwait', 
                                 'United Arab Emirates', 'Qatar', 'Oman', 'Yemen', 'Bahrain',
                                 'Lebanon')), aes(label=name),
            color = "darkblue", size = 3, check_overlap = FALSE) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 20, y = 35, label = "MØNA", 
           fontface = "italic", color = "grey22", size = 6) +
  
  xlab("lengdegrader") + ylab("breddegrader") +
  ggtitle("Midtøsten og Nord-Afrika") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "aliceblue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I wasn't even aware of that function. Apologies for not supplying the packages I used. I see you use giscoR (which I also wasn't aware of); I used rnaturalearth. Will change now, I think...

Comment: no worries! although if you found the answer helpful you may consider accepting / upvoting it; not an obligation but more of a manners thing. As for the packages: in principle they serve the same purpose, and can be used mostly interchangeably. There are some differences in license terms, but the chief differences are that giscoR has fewer technical faults in geometry, and rnaturalearth bases borders on actual control rather than legal borders (= it places Crimea in Russia, which I find abhorrent)

Comment: Thanks again - accepted now! I am pretty new to here, so please bear with me. Also from a Middle East perspective, the politics of giscoR are better than naturalearth.

Comment: as I said, no worries! :)